# Can't handle incoming call push notification when app is in background with Sinch iOS SDK

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, onesignal, sinch

I am using Sinch SDK to make voice call into my app and it is working fine when app is in foreground or terminated. But it is not working properly when app is in background. Sample App is working well provided with Sinch SDK. The only difference with Sample of My App is using OneSignal SDK additionally for push notification of other functionalities of my App.

So my question is

- Sinch SDK won't work with other push notification services (Ex: OneSignal SDK) ?

If user tap the push notification when app is in background then SINManagedPushDelegate's function

```
(void)managedPush:(id<SINManagedPush>)unused
didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload:(NSDictionary *)payload
forType:(NSString *)pushType 
{

}
```

is not called.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sinch provide 2 types of push notification - Standard APNS and VoIP push.
If you use standard APNS for Sinch incoming call and use OneSignal SDK together to handle push notification of other parts of App's feature then push notification is not working. You should use VoIP push notification with PushKit. I've used Pushkit and push notification delegate is successfully called. Should present local notification when app is in background to let user know incoming call.